# Why can't we get suppress messages in eclipse console when a command is run through java code

Tags: java

**Command Prompt:** C:>gpg --encrypt -r recipientname  FileToBeEncrypted.txt

Suppress Message iam getting

Not certain that you are using same key........

Use this key anyway?(y/N)-------If i press y,encryption of file is done.

**Eclipse:**
  Process runtime = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c gpg --encrypt -r recipientname  fileToBeEncrypted.txt");

system.out.println("Encrypted");

Waits for two secs and prints **Encypted** .No message is displayed in console and   enryption is not done.

Please help.

Comment: remove javascript tag, javascript != java

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. NO idea what you are asking.